# Short Story: Soldiers Can't Be Allowed To Come Back To Earth

Tags: story-identification

Two men are talking to each other on a space transport full of soldiers. They talk about how the men can never be allowed to return to earth because of the enhancements and training given to them. How they can't be deprogrammed and must instead spend the rest of their lives on a moon/asteroid base kept apart from their families.

Similar to the Star Trek: TNG episode "The Hunted".

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be something from John Scalzi's Old Man's War series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Scalzi#Fiction and [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Scalzi#Old_Man's_War_universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Scalzi#Old_Man%27s_War_universe)